# Xcode can't find SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

This seems to be a pretty weird issue. I'm following along with [this tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/11/2/falling-boxes-skspritenode-uitouch-skphysicsbody), and while I can build my project and run it on my phone, I keep getting this error in the IDE:
[image: picture of IDE showing the error]

> Cannot load underlying module for 'SpriteKit'

It says it cannot load the module for `SpriteKit` but that's weird because SpriteKit should be a native framework that must've been installed with my `Xcode`.

It is pretty annoying because `Xcode` is not context-aware, and code completion doesn't work for any object that's derived from `SpriteKit`.

Here's my system info:

- `Xcode` version: `Version 12.0 (12A7209)`
- `MacOS` version: `MacOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2)`

Is this a bug in `Xcode`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to solve 95% of "very strange" bugs:

1. Rebuild.
2. Close out Xcode and reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly why it's not working in your situation, but you might try re-creating the project this way:

From the Xcode top menu, select **File > New > Project**. Then in the screen that appears, make sure you select **iOS** from the tab bar and then select **Game**.

[image]

Click **Next** and when filling out the options in the next screen, make sure to select **SpriteKit** for the **Game Technology** option.

[image]

Once the new project is created, you can copy & paste any missing parts of your code into the appropriate code files in the new project. That is the "proper" way to create a new game project with SpriteKit.

Comment: Yeah that's what I exactly did.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Rebuilding and cleaning the Build Folder didn't solve the issue for me, unfortunately.

However, once I deleted Xcode's cached data the issue was resolved.

**To delete Xcode cached data:**

1. Close Xcode;
2. Open System Preferences on you Mac;
3. Go to General tab and select Storage section;
4. Locate Developer section (the system might take few moments to calculate the size of the files on the drive);
5. Press on 'i' icon next to Developer section;
6. Under "Xcode Project Build Files" locate cache list item (I already deleted it, so I don't remember the original name  )
7. Delete the cache and wait for the deletion process to complete;
8. Open Xcode. You're good to go!